# Find the limit of $c^n -n^{100}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need finding the limit of this expression:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c^n - n^{100} \ \text{ where } c\in \Bbb R^+$$

I know that when $0 < c <= 1$ then its  $-\infty$

But what about the others?

Thanks, Lior Cohen

Comment: For $c>1$ the exponent grows faster than any polynomial, so the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Thoughts**

I would just look at the individual cases for $c$ to solve.
I would divide the limit into two limits for this: $\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] = \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]$

Since the only thing that changes here is the $c$ and this is $c^{n}$, I would consider the classic cases for EXP-functions.

If $c > 1$ with ($x > 0$):

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \left( \frac{x}{1} \right)^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \underbrace{\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ x^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]}_{x^{n} \text{ grows asymptotically faster than } n^{100} \text{ in positive}}\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \infty\\
\end{align*}
$$

If $c = 1$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ 1^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= 1 - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= 1 - \infty\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= 1 - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= -\infty\\
\end{align*}
$$

If $|c| < 1$ with ($x > 0$):

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^{n} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \frac{1}{x^{n}} \right] - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= 0 - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= - \lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ n^{100} \right]\\
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= -\infty\\
\\
\Rightarrow 
\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] &= -\infty, ~\text{ where } c \leq 1\\
\end{align*}
$$

**Solution:**

- $\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] =
     +\infty, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{ where } c  > +1$
- $\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] =
     -\infty, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{ where } c \leq +1$
- $\lim_{{n} \rightarrow \infty} \left[ c^{n} - n^{100} \right] \in \left\{ -\infty, ~+\infty \right\}, ~ \text{ where } c \geq -1$ aka no solution

Comment: It's a beautiful answer, *but* you might want to keep in mind our guidelines for [enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Take a look particularly at the heading under that post entitled **Encourage New Users to Improve Their Posts**.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Oh I'm sorry ... I didn't know that. *Thanks for the advice!* Should I delete the answer and re-upload it later when the question has been improved?

Comment: That's a hard question. Your answer does not fall under the "hastily written answer" provision in that post. My suggestion was more just to make you aware of the policy for your future contributions.

Comment: Personally I'll add that in my own experience, there can easily be a lot of wasted effort in writing an answer that, however carefully written, turns out to miss the mark of what the OP actually wanted (but did not express clearly).

Answer (score 1):

It is known that exponential functions will always grow quicker than polynomials if the base is greater than $1$. In your case, the exponential function is $c^n$ and the polynomial is $n^{100}$. As you said, the answer is $-\infty$ when $0<c\leq 1$. But when $c>1$ the answer is $\infty$.